# Boost Asio TCP Server Handling multiple clients

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am new to network programming and the usage of Boost Asio library.

I successfully implemented a task for my requirement by modifying the Boost Asio *"Blocking TCP Echo Server and Client"* which performs transactions of operations between my Client and Server.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to connect multiple Clients with my Server.

I found some relevant links suggesting the usage of `async_accept` at the Server side.

So, I tried running the Boost Asio example: *"Async TCP Echo Server" with the "Blocking TCP Echo client"*, where the server distinguishes the different clients and addresses them accordingly.

But, my actual requirement should be like, instead of the Server completing the entire process for one Client, it [the server] has to perform same operations for the first client then go to the second client and perform those operations and then again come back to the first client and continue in this order until all operations are complete.

Is there any way or idea which could help me perform this flow using Boost Asio? Also I'm just using the "Blocking TCP Echo Client", which just has a normal `connect()` and not an `async_connect()`, now is that a problem?

Also, is it possible to communicate between multiple clients through the server using Boost Asio?

Thanking you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: yes sure, i'll add the code

Comment: Hi, Bjoern Urban, I have implemented a communication between Client and Server using Blocking TCP Echo concept. Now I want the Server to handle multiple clients, where a client at a time, does not complete the entire operations but rather completes a part of it with the Server and the next waiting Client continues the rest. I want the operations to be interleaved wrt the clients.

Comment: _"it [the server] has to perform same operations for the first client then go to the second client and perform those operations and then again come back to the first client and continue in this order until all operations are complete"_ - this bit is completely unclear. We don't know what "this order" means, "come back", "again", or what "operations" are.

Comment: Hi sehe it is like, the server sends the data to the first client and waits for the first client to acknowledge, then sends data to the second client and waits until it acknowledges after this the server would again request the first client to return the sent data and similarly ask the second client to return the data. I'm just using the Blocking TCP Echo Server and Client here for my code. I'm not sure as to what exact modification could be done! Here, the Clients do not loose the connection with the Server, they are called once again after the server completes the request of another Client.

Comment: My query is, is it possible to create this logic on my existing Synchronous Server or should I adopt an Asynchronous Server and Client for my operations, I'm confused amonst the two and wondering how it would work for the modifications

Comment: Switch from active waiting (where you do nothing but wait) to passive waiting (where you do something when the thing you're waiting for happens). In a sense, I'm always waiting for my phone to ring, but that doesn't mean that I'm not doing other things while I'm waiting. It just means I'll answer the phone if/when it rings. ASIO is arranging to answer the phone when it rings without actively waiting in a way that stops you from doing other things when the phone isn't ringing.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 models to handling multiple client concurrently on the server.

The one is to spawn a new thread for each client and then each thread handles each client synchronously. The second model is to use asynchronous APIs on a single thread all operating on a single service. When the accept completes, you then create a new worker thread and start the worker off the send and recv required by your protocol. You main thread goes back the accepting new connections.

With async, you prime the pump with an async accept and the call io_service run. When the accept completes, your callback runs. You now prime the pump again with further accepts (for more client) start async send and recv for the newly created client. Since all sends and recvs are non-blocking, the only time your thread sleeps is when it has nothing to do. Otherwise the io_service run method takes care of everything for you.

If you are blocking on sends and recvs, through, you cannot process more than one client concurrently.

Comment: So I'm planning to modify my Blocking TCP Echo Server code form to the Spawn Server format including my logic and I hope the problem of running multiple clients can be solved in this case. However, Ii'm un sure as to how I can implement the wait operation as mentioned previously between my Clients in executing parts of my server logic ? This is my biggest doubt!